# How to use generics to return child type from a parent method to support builder pattern

Tags: java, generics, method-chaining, builder-pattern

I am trying to support a builder pattern with inheritance, to allow chaining setters from parent and child class with no issue. For this I need the parent class to know to return back the child type to keep all methods exposed for chaining.

Here is a sample of code I wrote following this [article](http://javabitch.blogspot.com/2011/01/setter-chaining-generics.html) which I think should work, But as you'll see, the first example using a1 works fine, but if I change the order of the setters, the last setter is not recognized.

Problem is: once I call a method from the parent class, it will return itself as a type and not the child, even thought T is defined as the child type.

```
public class JavaApplication1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        A a1 = new B<>().setAge(0).setId(0).setName("name"); //Works fine
        A a2 = new B<>().setAge(0).setName("name").setId(0); //setId is not found

    }

    static class A<T extends A> {
        private String mpName;

        T setName(String name) {
            mpName = name;
            return (T) this;       
        }
    }

    static class B<T extends B> extends A<T> {
        private int mpAge;
        private int mpId;

        T setAge(int age) {
            mpAge = age;
            return (T) this;       
        }

        T setId(int id) {
            mpId = id;
            return (T) this;       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think Java can actually infer what you want the type argument to be in `new B<>()`, and I don't think its type system is sophisticated enough to propagate the `T extends B` information everywhere you want it to propagate.

Comment: Note that the article you're reading uses explicit type parameters, with no diamonds.

Comment: I did at first but the IDE warned that this was useless, and indeed the behavior stayed the same with it or without it.

Comment: (Note, you can get rid of the unsafe casts by adding a `protected T getThis` method (and having each class as either abstract or a leaf).)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I love solving that and not suppressing it. But the Unchecked cast simply is moved into a single method but it's still there. How was this method supposed to solve it?

Comment: @Alon No if the leaf classes are of the form `Leaf extends Abstact<Leaf>` then the can implement `protected Leaf getThis() { return this; }`, whilst the base class can declares `protected abstract T getThis();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should change you classes definitions as following:

```
static class A<T extends A<T>>
static class B<T extends B<T>> extends A<T>
```

`java.lang.Enum` uses the same declaration. You can find explanation why it's required in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211143/java-enum-definition).

Comment: @Alon rawtypes. The compiler should give a warning. Warnings are actually important.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline sounds like there is an important concept you're hinting at but I do not see that warning. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Alon See, for example, this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076830/why-does-using-raw-type-variables-affects-signatures-without-reference-to-type-p or indeed half the questions on java generics. But the compiler issues a warning which if heeded fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do we need parameterized types on the child class?

```
class Class {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Child().setAge(0).setId(0).setName("name");
    new Child().setAge(0).setName("name").setId(0);

  }

  static class Parent<C extends Parent> {
    private String mpName;

    C setName(String name) {
      mpName = name;
      return (C) this;
    }
  }

  static class Child extends Parent<Child> {
    private int mpAge;
    private int mpId;

    Child setAge(int age) {
      mpAge = age;
      return this;
    }

    Child setId(int id) {
      mpId = id;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that approach block Child from being extended further?