# Java Generic Type Erasure when using Optional

Tags: java, option-type

Definition in class:

```
class XXX {
    Map<String, Class> someMap;

    public <K, V>
    Optional<V> get(K key) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(getNullable(key));
    }

    public <K, V>
    V getNullable(K key) {
        //someMap already holds key -> class of V
        String value = DB.fetch(key);

        return gson.fromJson(value, someMap.get(key.toString()));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//xxx is an instance of XXX
Optional<ClassA> valueOpt = xxx.get(key); //this is fine
ClassA value = valueOpt.get(); //this is fine

//The intermediate valueOpt seems redundant, try to bypass it.
ClassA value = xxx.get(key).get(); //this does not work
```

My question: in the last line, seems the type info is deducible, why cannot it work? any workaround to make it work in one line?

Workarounds summary:
1) `xxx.get(key, ClassA.class)`
2) `(ClassA)xxx.get(key)`
3) `xxx.<K,ClassA>get(key)`

I still feel those are all workarounds because `ClassA value = xxx.getNullable(key);` can work.

Comment: My current workaround is: `public <K, V>
    Optional<V> get(K key, Class<V> valueType); ClassA value = xxx.get(key, ClassA.class).get();` but the 2nd param valueType is actually not used.

Comment: The reason that this fails is that type inference only works for generic parameters.  The expression `xxx.get(key).get()` has type `Object`, even though you know you're going to get `ClassA` from it.  If you _must_ do it in a single line, then just apply a cast.  `ClassA value = (ClassA) xxx.get(key).get();`

Comment: How is xxx declared? If I declare `Map<String,Optional<String>> xxx`, then `String value = xxx.get("").get()` works. If xxx is declared as a raw type, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43076991/1076640

Comment: Can you share your implementation of `get()`? I suspect `K` is unnecessary and `V` is unsafe.

Comment: @yshavit `xxx` presumably implements the preceding method signature.

Comment: The return type `V` is not deducible.  The only guarantee is that your `get` method will return an instance of `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You could be explicit with your method type params:

```
ClassA value2 = xxx.<String, ClassA>get(key).get();
```